# Login page on New window while using selenium webdriver

Tags: c#, angular, selenium, internet-explorer-11, mssql-jdbc

I was facing an issue, while I was trying to click on a link it opens a new window.
If I try manually it opens the expected link but if my automation code runs it opens the login page, and after login it routes to home page, not the actual page.

If I try manually at the browser initiated by automation code it also opens the window with the login page.

I am using selenium with C# and IE for the automation.

Comment: post the markup and/or scripts that are firing.  It's possible there are events needed which Selenium is not generating.  (mousedown/mouseup?) You probably also want to post the code you are using to generate the click.

Comment: Are you using the correct version of IE driver? Please provide [a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can have a better understanding of the issue and we can have a test in our sides. Thank you for your understanding.

Comment: @pcalkins: we have our own framework but to give you an idea I am doing these operations: 1) mouse hove on link to appear for dropdown 2) wait for links to be appeared in drop down 3) clicking on the link which opens the new window. With all these operations the new window will appear with Login page, but when I do all these operation in a page where I have logged in manually, its opening the expected link.

Comment: @Yu Zhou: right now I am using 3.141.5, but I tried 3.141.59 as well.

Comment: I think I may have misunderstood at first.  Have you automated the login process before doing this?

Comment: @pcalkins: yes I did

Comment: So if I understand correctly, it acts like it logs you in, but you are not and you are presented with another login prompt when navigating.  Do you know what sort of authorization the site is using?

Comment: @pcalkins I am not sure what authorization you are taking about, if you can give me some example I can get it for you.